# how to make OnNewIntent work inside tabs

Tags: java, android, nfc, onnewintent

I am working on a project where I have 3 tabs. The first tab is used to write information to NFC tag where the other 2 tabs are used to read the information from the NFC tag. However, I am facing a problem with OnNewIntent() method. As I understood correctly from reading online is that this method is used only in activities and not in fragments. I have looked at similar questions and answers but I don't fully understand what needs to be done to avoid this issue in my situation.

Here is my code for the first tab where I write some data to NFC tag:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
Button writebtn;
Tag tag;
EditText txtName, txtCountry, txtID;

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getContext());

    txtName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.personName);
    txtCountry= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.personCountry);
    txtID= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.personID);
    writebtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.nfcWriteBtn);

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container,false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(nfcAdapter !=null){
        enableForegroundDispatchSystem();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    disableForegroundDispatchSystem();
}

protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    // super.onNewIntent(intent);
    getActivity().getIntent();

    if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NFC tag discovered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        writebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                NdefMessage ndefMessage = createNdefMessage(txtName.getText().toString(), txtCountry.getText().toString(),txtID.getText().toString());

                writeNdefMessage(tag, ndefMessage);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onNewIntent(Intent intent)` belongs to `Activity` you cannot have it in  fragment. What you can do is pass the data to your fragment whenever `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` get called in `Activity`. To achieve this You   need to override `onNewIntent()` in Activity and notify the fragments about intent . Do not use `getIntent()` use the `intent` which is in argument.

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // Notify fragment about the new intent
}
```

And your Fragments method should look like .

```
 protected void onNewIntent( Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NFC tag discovered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        writebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NdefMessage ndefMessage = createNdefMessage(txtName.getText().toString(), txtCountry.getText().toString(),txtID.getText().toString());
                writeNdefMessage(tag, ndefMessage);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should make an Activity and add the first code snippet in there?

Comment: Yeah true, but I have all the code for writing and reading to NFC tag in Tabs, should I move the code to That activity to leave them in tabs? (i am kinda new to the whole Android development, so there is stuff that are beyond my knowledge)

Comment: See the updated answer . Get each fragment from tab notify them via a method or a callback interface . If you do not know how to do this then start searching.

Comment: Do you mean like to add this code to activity in onNewIntent @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        // Notify fragment about the new intent

       if(fragment instanceof Home){
            Home hm= (Home) fragment;
           hm.onNewIntent(intent);

        }

    }

Comment: Yeah ... Find each fragment and notify them .

Comment: it doesn't work, I mean I cannot get Toast (NFC tag discovered!) from the fragment to appear.

Comment: I already provided you the solution . Although i have no idea what you trying to achieve here  . You have set `OnClickListener` on New intent inside Fragment . What does that suppose to mean ? Figure out the issue and resolve it yourself . i.e Debug your code each step.